# Overriding data attribute styles with class styles

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, styled-components, postcss

I'm currently working on a headless implementation using the native popover API to have support across browsers. My examples are using Tailwind.

I've come across an interesting problem for the popover api, we have styles provided by the user agent stylesheet (browser) for the native API. For unsupported browsers we use a polyfill, but that polyfill makes use of a **data attribute**.

Data attributes in turn have the same specificity as a class. What this means, is that for unsupported browsers the user cannot override styles declared by the stylesheet unless it's an inline style or `!important`.

I had considered using `@layer`, but it doesn't seem like I can control that as a library author, the user needs to do that on their own. Any ideas?

I tried seeing if I could mess with the @layer, add the classes for them as inline styles (saw this would be a problem with css frameworks), tried using the where clause.

I am unsure of how to go forward. Perhaps the where clause somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to let the cascade override the styles with the following:

document.head.insertBefore(styleNode, document.head.firstChild);

Would love to see how some other approaches!